# Как доделать регулярное выражение для проверки значения на дробность?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция, которая проверяет значение на дробное

```
const isFloatNumberValue = (value: string) => (value.match(/^\d+([.,](\d{1,2})?)?$/g))
```

Ошибка в том, что мы можем вписать `00,01`, а должно быть `0,01`. Как исправить?

Comment: Вы в итоге хотите, чтобы числа с 00.01 проходили или наоборот?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, ваши регулярки не всегда будут работать должным образом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон regexp:

```
--Старая версия
^(?!0{2,})\d+([.,]\d+){0,1}$
```

Соответствуют шаблону:**12,33; 0,01; 12,00; 11; 1,1234567**
Не соответствует шаблону: **00,01; 124,; 0000,12**

UPD, действительно 01,11 пропускался предыдущей версией, исправил:

```
^(?!0{1,}\d+)\d+([.,]\d+){0,1}$
```

Если есть цифры после ноля и до запятой, совпадения не будет.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, функция определяющая дробное ли число, должна выглядить как-то так, без всяких регулярок:

```js
const a = '00000.00001';
const b = '92929';
function isDecimal (str){
  return !isNaN(Number(str)) && Number(str) % 1 === 0
}

function isDecimal_2 (str){
  return str.split('.').length === 1;
}
console.log(isDecimal(a), isDecimal(b));
console.log(isDecimal_2(a), isDecimal_2(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input { outline: none }
:invalid { border: 1px solid red }
:valid { border: 1px solid green }
```

```html
<input pattern="^(0|[1-9]\d*)([.,]\d{0,2})?$" required autofocus value="0.12">
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, 
Если с именно одной цифрой до точки или запятой обязательной, то так:

```
^[0-9][.,][0-9]+$
```

Специально для пользователя @And скрины с https://regex101.com/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если необходимо с несколькими нулями перед точкой, то можете воспользоваться следующим выражением:

```
^[0-9]*[.,][0-9]+$ //В Этом случае будет много чисел до точки и даже пройдёт .123
```

Если необходимо только с обязательным символом до точки(чтобы .123 не проходило) и неограниченным количеством символов перед ней, то можно так:

```
^\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?$
```

Вариант с ограниченным количеством знаков после запятой `2`

```
^[0-9][.,](\d{1,2})$
```

Comment: Не одно и регулярки не дает верное решение.

Comment: @And с чего это вдруг??? Проверять хоть пробовали?

Comment: С того, что не дает! Прежде, чем писать, проверять нужно, на каком-нибудь `regex100` или ином месте.

Comment: @And именно на нём и проверял!!! Не верите - проверьте сами, прежде чем писать подобные комментарии. https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Denis640Kb видимо вы не совсем поняли вопрос, имелось виду избавиться от ведущих нулей у чисел, т.е. *12,21* или *143,22* так же должны подходить под шаблон. Предложенные вами варианты справедливы для целых чисел диапазона от 0 до 9. и любой десятичной т.е. для *1.11*, но не для *10,01*.